# I want to add a glowing effect on the button when a value in the pickerinput is changed in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I want to have a glow to the refresh button when I change the pickerinput.
I have been able to get the glow but the problem is that this is glowing from the start. I don't want this to glow from the start and Yes! it is necessary to have a default selected value.
I hope this is clear enough. I'm sorry if I didn't adhere to the guidelines. I'm still learning.
Thank you in advance!

```
library("shiny")
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyjs)

#Created Ui having picker input, action button and Css for it

ui <- tagList(shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
              fluidPage(
  tags$h2("Select / Deselect all"),
  actionButton("button_1", "Refresh Plot",style= "animation: none;"),
  pickerInput(
    inputId = "p1",
    label = "Select all option",
    choices = rownames(mtcars),
    multiple = TRUE,
    options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE), selected = rownames(mtcars)[1]
  )),
tags$head(tags$style(HTML('@keyframes glowing {
                      0% { background-color: #4a257a !important; box-shadow: 0 0 5px #0795ab; }
                      50% { background-color: #6632ad !important; box-shadow: 0 0 20px #43b0d1; }
                      100% { background-color: #4a257a !important; box-shadow: 0 0 5px #0795ab; }
                      }
                                             '))))


server <- function(input, output) {
  observe({
    
    runjs(paste0('$("#button_1").css("animation","glowing 5000ms infinite")'))
    delay(5000, runjs(paste0('$("#button_1").css("animation","none")')))
    print(input$p1)
    })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `observe({...})` to `observeEvent(input$p1, {...}, ignoreInit = TRUE)`